# It it possible to have multiple Locales in one same MessageFormat?

Tags: java, json, escaping, java-17, messageformat

I have the following JSON example below:

```
{
    "value": 946.2,
    "description": "O valor é R$ 946,20."
}
```

I need to use MessageFormat to JUnit test this JSON example, but I get an invalid value because my Locale is not in english. If I change my Locale to english instead of brazilian portuguese I get an invalid description because the currency value is displayed in English.

Here's my code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);

System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("""
'{'
    "value": {0},
    "description": "O valor é {0,number,currency}."
'}'
""", new BigDecimal(946.2)));
```

How can I format the value or the description in order to get the JSON as displayed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `String.format` solution with two inner (localized, customized) `NumberFormat`ters:

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class OtherMain {

  private static final Locale LOCALE_PT_BR = new Locale.Builder().
      setLanguage("pt").
      setRegion("BR").
      build();
  
  private static final NumberFormat DEFAULT_NUMBER_FMT
      = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
  private static final NumberFormat MY_SPECIAL_NUMBER_FMT
      = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(LOCALE_PT_BR);

  static {
    // this disables "thousands sperarator", we can adjust DEFAULT_NUMBER_FMT as well...
    MY_SPECIAL_NUMBER_FMT.setGroupingUsed(false);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(99946.2);
    System.out.format("""
                      {
                        "value": %s,
                        "description": "O valor é %s."
                      }
                      """,
        DEFAULT_NUMBER_FMT.format(num),
        MY_SPECIAL_NUMBER_FMT.format(num)
    );
  }
}
```

Prints:

```json
{
  "value": 99,946.2,
  "description": "O valor é R$ 99946,20."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, no problem! But:

- `Locale.setDefault` is harsh! (for test it can be tolerable.... but i don't want to look up that bug..)
- (I "don't like" `MessageFormat`... it uses `StringBuffer`  internally(Mr. performance killer & memory dumper).)

As long as you can handle the "complexity", it can be done like:

```scala
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainSimple {

  // Brazilian Locale:
  private static final Locale LOCALE_PT_BR = new Locale.Builder().
      setLanguage("pt").
      setRegion("BR").
      build();
  // US number format:
  private static final NumberFormat DEFAULT_NUMBER_FMT = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // MessageFormat instance, with format (with 2! parameters) and Locale:
    MessageFormat mainFmt = new MessageFormat("""
                      '{'
                          "value": {0},
                          "description": "O valor é {1,number,currency}. <-- trick 1 "
                      '}'
                      """, LOCALE_PT_BR);
    
    final BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(946.2);
    // trick 2:
    Object[] params = {DEFAULT_NUMBER_FMT.format(num), num};
    // do it:
    System.out.println(mainFmt.format(params));
  }
}
```

Outline:

- Constants for:

  - Brazilian (outer format) locale.
  - US/Standard (inner) number format for custom (non brazilian) formatting/this particular number.
- [`MessageFormat` has a constructor with locale parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/MessageFormat.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,java.util.Locale))! (*we use that*, and call it outer format/locale(`mainFmt`))
- Int the format we "trick a little" and use 2 parameters: `{0}` and `{1,number,currency}`
- We trick on: Pass the first parameter as a (US-formatted number) ***`String`***, the second as had. (`Object[] params = {DEFAULT_NUMBER_FMT.format(num), num}`)
- finally format (& print to out).

Prints:

```json
{
    "value": 946.2,
    "description": "O valor é R$ 946,20."
}
```

Comment: I ended up by writing the exact same code and found one other problem to my use case. How can I have "O valor é R$ 1946,20." instead of "O valor é R$ 1.946,20."? Is it possible? Should do one more hacky code and replace all dots with a regular expression? Or does exist a pattern such as ##.# that maintains the currency symbol? One other point, what would you use instead of MessageFormat? I chose it over String.format because MessageFormat allows us to reuse variables because the patterns are positioned and String.format can't.

Comment: sorry, i get `{"value": 99,946.2,"description": "O valor é R$ 99.946,20."}`

Comment: ... but `99946,20` (without thousands separtor) is *not* "brazilian currency format"!!!

Comment: and if you say "test json" and "java 17" ....nowadays there are better ways to "test json" ..than with a MessageFormat... (except the json was produced with MessageFormat...and this exactly is to be tested..)

Comment: Yes, you are right, but my use case demands to hide the thousands separator because this is common practice here, also now we have a value not accepted by JSON format.

Comment: The JSON is actually used with Jackson ObjectMapper to map a record class.

Comment: why not use (the same) objectmapper in test!? ;)

Comment: Because value and description are parameterized.

Comment: ...yes: 1. you put parameters into your test,2.  you get a json back 3. you use objectmapper to map the result. 4. you make assertions on the result(object not string) based on parameters... weekend! :)

Comment: Could you please edit this answer and post a code snippet of your last comment?